# jQuery: select a single element with same class name without repeating code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I currently have a javascript function that blurs an image when hovered over. Each of these images represents a project, and I have 5 of these projects with the class "individual-project". An img inside an individual project div has the class "project-img".

```
$('.individual-project').eq(0).hover(function() {
    $('.project-img').eq(0).css({'filter': 'blur(3px)', 'transform': 'scale(1.1, 1.1)', '-webkit-filter': 'blur(3px)', '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1.1, 1.1)', '-moz-filter': 'blur(3px)', '-moz-transform': 'scale(1.1, 1.1)'});
}, function() {
    $('.project-img').eq(0).css({'filter': 'blur(0px) brightness(100%)'});
});
```

Currently I need to repeat this block 5 times and change the value inside the eq function for each project to blur it without blurring all of the other ones. Any help with the getting the selectors to work for individual divs with the same class would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do the `.individual-project`s have any children?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I should have specified. Each .individual-project is a div that has the .project-img and a <p> inside.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the HTML your code is running on in your question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance My apologies. Fortunately, SamVK 's solution below worked. If you still want me to add the html, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to affect the project image in each project, you want to use a contextual lookup.

```js
$('.individual-project').hover(function(e) {
  $('.project-img', e.target).css({
    'filter': 'blur(3px)',
    'transform': 'scale(1.1, 1.1)',
    '-webkit-filter': 'blur(3px)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1.1, 1.1)',
    '-moz-filter': 'blur(3px)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(1.1, 1.1)'
  });
}, function(e) {
  $('.project-img', e.target).css({
    'filter': 'blur(0px) brightness(100%)'
  });
});
```

The second argument you can optionally give to the `$()` method is the context in which to search for the matches.  `$(selector)` is the same as doing `$(selector, document)`.  Giving the second argument overrides the default context.

Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: Could you not just do `$('.project-img', this)`?

Comment: Provided you're not using an arrow function, sure.